# while hide the soft keyboard it leave's white space in the screen

Tags: maps, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-z

I am using bing map, in which when I  hide  the soft keyboard it leave's the white space in the Screen.This problem only occurs in Sony Xperia J handset

[image]

Comment: FYI - your image link doesn't work. You might want to upload it here so that we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: @bmdixon i updated now

Comment: Does it do this only in the app pictured, or in every app?

Comment: As dan asked is it only that app? Have you tried a different keyboard to see what happens?

Comment: @DanHulme only this app and only its happened sony devices\

Comment: So it's an app related issue. I would contact the app developer and let them know that this happens on Sony devices. Maybe they'll post a fix for it! You could try a different keyboard too and see how that fares.

Comment: @RossC Different keyboard means

Comment: ? I don't understand? Have you tried installing a different keyboard from the Play Store and seeing if this issue happens when you use it?

Comment: Are you using custom rom ?

Comment: @sameer no,Mine stock ROM

Comment: Is this app from playstore?. Can you give me a link, so that I can check on my Xperia U

Comment: @sameer its not a Play store App ,I am updated my Screen shot